# Como configurar um projeto Laravel com VueJs

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Saudação, estou um simples projeto Laravel e gostaria de configurar meu projeto para ele aceitar o vue.js, mas estou tendo essa mensagem de erro;

```
"Use of undefined constant titulo - assumed 'titulo' (View: C:\Users\Wladimir\Documents\projetos php\imoveis\resources\views\imoveis\create.blade.php)"
```

Poderiam por favor dá uma olhada no meu repositório para ver o que está configurado errado.

[Meu Repositório](https://github.com/wladyband/imoveis/blob/master/resources/views/imoveis/create.blade.php)

E assim que está a estrutura do meu projeto

acredito que seja coisa simples;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

================================================

Eu fiz assim `{{ $titulo }}`, mesmo assim não pegou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem que ajeitar essa linha: https://github.com/wladyband/imoveis/blob/master/resources/views/imoveis/create.blade.php#L48

Você está colocando apenas `titulo` ao invés de `$titulo`, dessa forma o laravel entende como uma constante.

Fonte: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data

Comment: fiz uma atualização na postagem, poderia dá uma olhada, mas só adiantando a sua sugestão gerou o mesmo problema

Comment: Ele pegou com o @, porque será que pegou com o @, existe alguma explicação pra isso.

Comment: Funcionou assim `@{{ titulo }}`? Se foi assim é porque o laravel e o vue.js usam chaves duplas pra variáveis, colocando o  `@` na frente evita o conflito do Laravel com o Vue.